# Cannot log DOM elements on the mounted hook of vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-cli

For some reason, on the mounted hook I cant seem to log DOM elements on the browser while I am potentially lokking to loop through elements or , as my final resort just work on a specific index of a HTML Collection:

the following is the vue component I am having an issue with:

```
<template>
  <full-page ref="fullpage" id="fullpage" :options="options">
            <slider class="section" :auto="false">
                <slider-item v-animate-css="'fadeIn'">
                    <h1 class="mainTitle">PROJECT GORILLA</h1>
                </slider-item>
                <slider-item v-for="bkg in bkgImg" :style="{backgroundSize:'cover', 
                backgroundImage: 'url(' + bkg + ')'}">
                <h1 class="mainTitle">PROJECT GORILLA</h1>
                </slider-item>
        </slider>
  </full-page>
</template>
<script>
import { Slider, SliderItem } from 'vue-easy-slider'
import pinkBkg from '@/assets/img/IMG_2473.jpg'
import redBkg from '@/assets/img/IMG_4674.jpg'
import blueBkg from '@/assets/img/IMG_4716.jpg'
import greenBkg from '@/assets/img/IMG_2013.jpg'

export default {
    data(){
      return {
        options:{
          licenseKey:null
        },
        bkgImg:[pinkBkg,redBkg,blueBkg,greenBkg]
      }
    },
    components: {
        Slider,
        SliderItem
    },
    mounted(){
        let slides = document.getElementsByClassName("slider-item");

        console.log(slides[0]);


    }
}
</script>
<style>

.slider-item:nth-of-type(1) { background-color:black;}

.slider-item > .wrap {
    display:flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items:center;
}
h1.mainTitle {
    position:fixed;
    z-index:99;
    color:white !important;
}
.slider-item {
    z-index:98 !important;
}

</style>
```

Bare in mind that I am currently using the webpack template for vue-cli. To be honest jQuery has crossed my mind as a last resort but I really don't want to
resort to that because its is important that the application has a decent performance...
 in this case console.log returns undefined. But If I copy and past the code on the browser then it would work fine.

Answer (score 1):

When your component is mounted, it doesn't necessarily mean the child components within it are fully rendered.

As you can see in your template, there are no HTML elements with `class="slider-item"`. I imagine these appear later when the `SliderItem` components are rendered.

What you can do is add a `ref` attribute to any element or component you want to reference.

For example

```html
<slider-item ref="sliderItem" v-animate-css="'fadeIn'">
  <h1 class="mainTitle">PROJECT GORILLA</h1>
</slider-item>
<slider-item ref="sliderItemRepeater" v-for="bkg in bkgImg"
             :style="{backgroundSize:'cover', backgroundImage: 'url(' + bkg + ')'}">
  <h1 class="mainTitle">PROJECT GORILLA</h1>
</slider-item>
```

Then in your `mounted` hook, you can access

```js
this.$refs.sliderItem // the first, non-repeating component
this.$refs.sliderItemRepeater // an array of the repeated components
```

See https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-edge-cases.html#Accessing-Child-Component-Instances-amp-Child-Elements

Comment: that is some interesting information, thanks! I will definitely look into this and come back if I find any issues.

Comment: It seems like with $ref so far I can only get reference to the component but not the actual div element which is strange... I even tried logging the $el property hoping to be able to get the element. My end goal is to be able to access the H1.mainTitle for me to be able to animate it. I even tried adding a refference to the h1 and it didnt work either.

Comment: You could always put the ref attribute on the `<h1>` and access it directly. You should explain in your question what it is you actually want to do

Comment: And what if you use slots? if you pass in the children as slots?